# List objects in OU with specific security group

Tags: vb.net, powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I currently use a script to display all computers assigned to a security group. The script I currently use is a VB Script:

```
Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://cn=My Group,ou=Security Groups,ou=_Groups - standard,ou=city,ou=state,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=tld,")
For Each objMember in objGroup.Members
Wscript.Echo objMember.Name 
Next
```

This script works and pulls every member of My Group from the entire domain. This works, but I'm trying to filter it a bit. I want to search computers through a specific OU. I have tried the following code to no avail:

```
Dim objGroup
Dim objMachine
Dim objMatch

Set objGroup = GetObject("LDAP://cn=My Group,ou=Security Groups,ou=_Groups - standard,ou=city,ou=state,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=tld")
Set objMachine = GetObject("LDAP://ou=Building,ou=street,ou=city,ou=state,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=tld")

Dim c
For each c in objGroup
if c = objMachine Then
Wscript.Echo objMachine.Name
end if
next
```

The code executes without error, but I do not see any output. I then decided to tackle this problem in PowerShell.

```
$computer = Get-ADGroup -searchbase 'ou=Building,ou=street,ou=city,ou=state,dc=my,dc=domain,dc=tld' -Filter * ` |
Get-ADGroup -Filter {(Name -eq "My Group") -or (Name -eq "My Other Group")} ` |
Select-Object -Unique ` |
Sort-Object DistinguishedName; 
$computer | Select-Object Name, DistinguishedName; 
export-csv C:\Temp\Result.csv
```

This throws a few errors in ISE stating that the cmdlet Get-ADGroup doesn't support pipeline input or the input didn't match. At the end, it lists the two groups, as well as their distinguished names.

I would like to get a computer name as well as the Distinguished Name for every computer that is a member of either "My Group" or "My Other Group" in the Building OU as well as each OU under that OU. I would prefer a way to do it in PowerShell, but I can use VB Script as well.

(Sorry if I'm missing any critical information, this is my first posting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break this task into:

1. Find Group Members
2. Determine whether they reside in OU

Finding group members is easy with `Get-ADGroupMember`:

```
$Members = Get-ADGroupMember "SecurityGroup"
```

To determine whether a member resides in an OU, check to see if the OU distinguished name matches the last part of the Member's distinguished name:

```
$OU = "OU=Specific,OU=Computers,OU=Office1,DC=domain,DC=tld"
$MembersInOu = $Members |Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*,$OU"}
```

You can now combine this into a single pipeline:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "SecurityGroup" |Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*,$OU"}
```

Comment: For the most part, this works quite well. I just run into the following error when I try to do it in a large group: `FullyQualifiedErrorId : The size limit for this request was exceeded,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember` and I have no idea how else to break it down further.